# Disabling Saving Alerts from Macro that saving multiple files in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I created that loops through a drop down list and saves files in a certain location.  The code works fine but I have over 200 files I need to save and the status bar for saving the file pops up and the whole process is extremely slow.  My question is there any way to speed up the process maybe disabling the saving status updates?  As you can see I inserted Application.Displayalerts = False everywhere to no avail.  Here's my code

```
Sub File_Generator()

Dim cell As Range
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim strFilename As String
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook

Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSummary = Sheets("Master Plan")

With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each cell In Worksheets("Team Breakdown").Range("$C$3:$C$221")
If cell.Value = "" Then
counter = counter + 1
 Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

 Else
 'progress in status bar
 counter = counter + 1
 Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

 With wsSummary
    .Range("$B$2").Value = cell.Value
    strFilename = wbThis.Sheets("Master Plan").Range("N1").Value & "\" & cell.Value & " Master Plan"
    wsSummary.Copy
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wbNew.SaveAs strFilename
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wbNew.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 End With
 End If
 Next cell
 Set wbThis = Nothing
 Set wsSummary = Nothing
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like it's the actual saving which is the problem: if it were faster you wouldn't see the "saving" message at all.  How large are the files, and are you saving them locally, or to a network drive?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm saving them on a network drive

Comment: Unless you could speed up the actual disk write then disabling the updates likely won't save you any time in the whole process.